# write.table to new directory

Tags: r

Is there any way to use write() and write.table() so that the output file is in a different directory than the working directory? It tried setting the path to the output file before the filename, and just get an error message.

Comment: Might your error message be due to the fact that the directory you are trying to `setwd()` to does not exist? If so, use `dir.create()`.

Comment: can you post the actual `write.table` line you've tried?

Comment: Also, if you're using Windows, don't forget the path needs to use forward slashes `C:/Users/etc`

Answer (score 8):

If you're using windows, `R` will know to go outside the current directory if it sees `C:/` first (presumably other mounted drives too). With Macs it will go outside the current wd if it sees `/`. So:

1. Mac OS X:

   ```
   write.table(foo, file="/users/name/folder/filename.ext")
   ```
2. Windows

   ```
   write.table(foo, file="C:/users/name/folder/filename.ext")
   ```

Always test to make sure you have the path right first!

```
list.files("C:/...")
list.files("/....")       #Give errors if path doesn't exist as typed
```

So if you're in `/users/parent/subdir` and you want to reference something in `parent`, you must type out the full path - `write.table(foo, "parent/name.ext")` will tell R to make a file: `/users/parent/subdir/parent/name.ext`.

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
write.table(foo,file="../bar/baz.txt")
```

Or you can use absolute paths - nomenclature will depend on your operating system.