# Specify path in write.csv function

Tags: r

I have a simple syntax question: Is there a way to specify the path in which to write a csv file within the `.csv` function itself?

I always do the following:

```
setwd("C:/Users/user/Desktop")
write.csv(dt, "my_file.csv", row.names = F)
```

However, I would like to skip the `setwd()` line and include it directly in the `write.csv()` function. I can't find a path setting in the `write.csv` documentation file. Is it possible to do this exclusively in `write.csv` without using `write.table()` or having to download any packages?

I am writing around 300 `.csv` files in a script that runs auomatically everyday. The loop runs slower when using `write.table()` than when using `write.csv()`. The whole reason I want to include the path in the `write.csv()` function is to see if I can decrease the time it takes to execute any further.

Comment: It's simply `write.csv(dt, "C://Users/user/Desktop/my_file.csv", row.names = F)`

Comment: `write.csv(dt, "C:/Users/user/Desktop/my_file.csv", row.names = F)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [write.table to new directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652019/write-table-to-new-directory)

Comment: What you're calling the path is labeled as the `file` argument for `write.csv`. The docs `?write.csv`: "either a character string naming a file or a connection open for writing. "" indicates output to the console."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I typically set my "out" path in the beginning and then just use `paste()` to create the full filename to save to.

```
path_out = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\'
fileName = paste(path_out, 'my_file.csv',sep = '')
write.csv(dt,fileName)
```

or all within `write.csv()`

```
path_out = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\'
write.csv(dt,paste(path_out,'my_file.csv',sep = ''))
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a specialized function for this: `file.path`:

```
path <- "C:/Users/user/Desktop"
write.csv(dt, file.path(path, "my_file.csv"), row.names=FALSE)
```

Quoting from `?file.path`, its purpose is:

> Construct the path to a file from components in a platform-independent way.

Some of the few things it does automatically (and  `paste` doesn't):

- Using a platform-specific path separator
- Adding the path separator between path and filename (if it's not already there)

Answer (score 1):

Another way might be to build a wrapper function around the write.csv function and pass the arguments of the write.csv function in your wrapper function.

`write_csv_path <- function(dt,filename,sep,path){
    write.csv(dt,paste0(path,filename,sep = sep))
}`

Example

`write_csv_path(dt = mtcars,filename = "file.csv",sep = "",path = ".\\")`

Answer (score 0):

In my case this works fine,

1. create a folder -> `mmult.datas`
2. copy its directory-> `C:/Users/seyma/TP/tp.R/tp.R5 - Copy`
3. give a name of your .csv -> `df.Bench.csv`
4. do not forget the write your data.frame -> `df`
5. `write.csv(df, file ="C:/Users/seyma/TP/tp.R/tp.R5 - Copy/mmult.datas/df.Bench.csv")`

for more you can check [the link](http://www.instantr.com/2012/12/11/exporting-a-dataset-from-r/)