# Write.CSV to a folder showing file not defined error

Tags: python, csv

I have a script which produces multiple .csv files and each .csv file has its own name which is a variable. I am trying to save these files to a specific path instead of saving them to the Python folder.

I have tried this tutorial [Specify path in write.csv function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089219/specify-path-in-write-csv-function) but it gave me this error: NameError: name 'file' is not defined and I tried to find other people who had the same issue when using write.csv but was unable to find any

I am on MacOS

Here is the code:

```
                path = '/Users/chris/Desktop/cd'

                fcsv = csv.writer(open, file.path(f'{finalitem}.csv', 'w', newline=''))
                fcsv.writerow(headers)
                fcsv.writerows(datarows)
```

I have tried multiple examples of writing csv to file path and have had 0 success. If anyone has any ideas or suggestions I'd love to hear them.

Here is my full code:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from datetime import datetime

headers = []
datarows = []
# define 1-1-2020 as a datetime object
after_date = datetime(2020, 1, 1)

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {"User-Agent": "Safari/537.36"}
    r = s.get('https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-dogecoin-addresses-20.html')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

    # select all tr elements (minus the first one, which is the header)
    table_elements = soup.select('tr')[1:]
    address_links = []
    for element in table_elements:
        children = element.contents  # get children of table element
        url = children[1].a['href']
        last_out_str = children[8].text
        # check to make sure the date field isn't empty
        if last_out_str != "":
            # load date into datetime object for comparison (second part is defining the layout of the date as years-months-days hour:minute:second timezone)
            last_out = datetime.strptime(last_out_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
            # if check to see if the date is after 2020/1/1
            if last_out > after_date:
                address_links.append(url)

    for url in address_links:

        r = s.get(url)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        table = soup.find(id="table_maina")

        #Get the Doge Address for the filename

        item = soup.find('h1').text
        newitem = item.replace('Dogecoin', '')
        finalitem = newitem.replace('Address', '')
        finalitem = finalitem.replace(' ', '')


        #Get the profit

        sections = soup.find_all(class_='table-striped')

        for section in sections:
            oldprofit = section.find_all('td')[11].text
            removetext = oldprofit.replace('USD', '')
            removetext = removetext.replace(' ', '')
            removetext = removetext.replace(',', '')
            profit = float(removetext)

        # Compare profit to goal

        goal = float(50000)

        if profit < goal:
            continue

        if table:

                    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
                        heads = row.find_all('th')
                        if heads:
                            headers = [th.text for th in heads]
                        else:
                            datarows.append([td.text for td in row.find_all('td')])

                    path = '/Users/chris/Desktop/cd'

                    fcsv = csv.writer(open(f'{finalitem}.csv', 'w', newline=''))
                    fcsv.writerow(headers)
                    fcsv.writerows(datarows)
```

Comment: are you closing the file after you write to it?

Comment: Is this your full code? Where is `file` defined?

Comment: See [Reading and Writing CSV Files in Python](https://realpython.com/python-csv/).

Comment: @AndrewRyan For the specific CSV file, I am writing the data to it and closing it to later access it.

Comment: @C.Nvis I updated the post with my full code. What should I define the file as? Please pardon my ignorance I am new to python.

Comment: @alwayshope430 you never do fcsv.close() in your script to close your function

Comment: That tutorial is for the R programming language, not Python. While something very similar *could* be done, it's not recommended because the file won't be get closed until the script ends and potentially won't writing out any data that might have been buffered. The preferred technique is to use a `with` statement as shown in @AndrewRyan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can have automatic file closing using a `with` statement:

```
with open(f'{finalitem}.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fcsv = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers) # assuming headers is a list object
    fcsv.writeheader()
    fcsv.writerows(datarows)
```

The error that you are having is that you are wrapping `file.path()` with elements that should be part of the open function and that you may be wanting to refer to the path variable instead of a `path()` function for your naming/downloading path.